# reduceByKey not taking generic parameter

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark

I want to reduce generic values in Key Values based on function supplied
but it gives error :

```
value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, T)]
val reduce = (rDD:RDD[(String,T)]) => rDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => y)**
                                          ^
```

Does reduceByKey doesn't work with generics.

Also

```
val map = rdd.map()
val reduce = (rDD:RDD[(String,T)]) => rDD.reduceByKey((x,y) => y)
```

When I try to curry it using

```
map andThen reduce
```

It again says cannot find **andThen** symbol

**Update**

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

class Aggragator[T]( val rdd:RDD[String], function:Function[String,T]){

val mapped = rdd.map(x => (x,function.apply(x)))
val reduce = mapped.reduceByKey((x,y) => y)

}

object Aggragator{

val conf = new SparkConf()
.setMaster("local[2]")
 .setAppName("xx")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("1","2"))
val reduced = new Aggragator[Int](rdd, (x:String) => x.toInt).reduce.collect()
  def main( args: Array[String] ) {
    println(reduced)
 }}
```

Comment: Where is `T` defined? Please post a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: T is the type of class

Comment: Show us the complete code example. This compiles fine for me.

Comment: Hi I have created the class , It doesnt show error in ide but when I compile the code it throws error

Comment: All that's missing is the `ClassTag` context bound in your class: `class Aggragator[T: ClassTag]`